# How to improve code generator when using iterators in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

The following [two functions](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=02b3d78b9022f077704d680d9c8a71d0) generate very different resulting assembly language:

```rust
pub struct X {
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
    c: u64,
    d: u64,
    e: u64,
    f: u64,
}

pub fn f(a: u8, x: X) -> u64 {
    [
        (0b000001, x.a),
        (0b000010, x.b),
        (0b000100, x.c),
        (0b001000, x.d),
        (0b010000, x.e),
        (0b100000, x.f),
    ]
    .into_iter()
    .find(|(bb, _)| (*bb & a) != 0)
    .map_or(0, |(_, m)| m)
}

pub fn g(a: u8, x: X) -> u64 {
    match a {
        _ if (a & 0b000001) != 0 => x.a,
        _ if (a & 0b000010) != 0 => x.b,
        _ if (a & 0b000100) != 0 => x.c,
        _ if (a & 0b001000) != 0 => x.d,
        _ if (a & 0b010000) != 0 => x.e,
        _ if (a & 0b100000) != 0 => x.f,
        _ => 0,
    }
}
```

They do the same thing: based on a bit pattern, return the proper value. I prefer `f` because it separates the data and the logic, but it results in inferior assembly. Because I'm running simulations, a little is a lot. (see assembly with above playground link, generate release asm)

In `f`, Rust unnecessarily builds the array in memory instead of recognizing that the values are used and immediately discarded. `g` mashes the data and logic together, but Rust simply does the comparisons then returns the results, as you would expect.

Is there anything I can do to help this iterator-style code generate better code or am I better off writing imperative style?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but it looks like you could use `leading_zeros()` here.

Comment: @DanGetz -- haha, yeah in this scenario. Unfortunately, I've got much more complex evaluations. Not sure how ctz would simplify this anyway, since I'm just comparing bits.

Comment: Funnily enough, they generate nearly the same assembly if you don't preload the values themselves and instead use references: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b330414e43785494bb9e887cbd88e456). Perhaps its easier to optimize the fixed-offsets of the references upfront rather than trying to backtrack where the original value came from in order to elide the array.

Comment: Also, you may get some performance benefit from passing `X` by reference rather than by value since that would incur less register-pressure/stack-movements and I'm doubtful that the indirection would cost anything if its already in the cache. But of course, measure!

Comment: @kmdreko Oh you're right. That's non obvious. The function argument being a reference isn't enough. The array values need to be references in order to optimize well. What a headscratcher.

Comment: *"... or am I better off writing imperative style?"* - I personally think the match version here is much clearer than the iterator version anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the slightly shorter

```rust
pub fn h(a: u8, x: X) -> u64 {
    match a.trailing_zeros() {
        0 => x.a,
        1 => x.b,
        2 => x.c,
        3 => x.d,
        4 => x.e,
        5 => x.f,
        _ => 0
    }
}
```

Not sure how its assembly looks.